# R studio: When loading a package, strange characters appear in the console

Tags: r, rstudio

Just like what is shown in the picture, the hook sign appears in strange Chinese character

[image]

I changed default text encoding to 'UTF-8', which is in 'saving', the 'code' section in 'global options' settings. But it does not help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue, apparently due to the cli package that tidyverse uses for its startup text, for which a fix is planned ([tidyverse issue thread](https://github.com/tidyverse/tidyverse/issues/256); [cli issue thread](https://github.com/r-lib/cli/issues/424)). In the meantime, [per Gábor Csárdi](https://github.com/tidyverse/tidyverse/issues/256#issuecomment-1044604327),

> A workaround is to set `options(cli.unicode = FALSE)`.

Comment: Is there a way to permanently change this setting? If there is, should I do it? Will it cause any trouble in the future? Thank you SOOO MUCH!